# Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage returning Success but onMessageReceived is not calling

Tags: wear-os

Working on Wear application, I have created Wear application with Mobile and wear applications. Sending data from mobile application, through "**MessageApi.SendMessageResult**" and returning status is **SUCCESS** but message is not received in wear application. Please find the code in below and let me know i am missing any thing.

**Mobile App Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";
private static final String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "/message";

private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mApiClient.disconnect();
}

private void init() {
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_view );
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.input );
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_send );

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                mAdapter.add(text);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, text);

            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage( final String path, final String text ) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Previous code
           NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient ).await();

            Log.d("MessageAPI","nodes :: "+nodes);
            for(com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                Log.d("MessageAPI","nodes for :: "+node);
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes() ).await();
                Log.d("MessageAPI","node.getId() : "+node.getId());
                Log.d("MessageAPI","text.getBytes() : "+text.getBytes());
                Log.d("MessageAPI","path : "+path);
                Log.d("MessageAPI","nodes result Status:: "+result.getStatus().isSuccess());
            }

           /*PutDataMapRequest putDMR = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
            putDMR.getDataMap().putAll(getDatMap());
            PutDataRequest request = putDMR.asPutDataRequest();
            DataApi.DataItemResult result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mApiClient, request).await();
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v("MessageAPI", "nodes DataMap: " + getDatMap() + " sent successfully to data layer ");
            } else {
                // Log an error
                Log.v("MessageAPI", "nodes ERROR: failed to send DataMap to data layer");
            }*/



            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mEditText.setText( "" );
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    sendMessage(START_ACTIVITY, "Wear my TEST MESSAGE");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
private DataMap getDatMap(){

    DataMap  dataMap = new DataMap();
    dataMap.putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
    dataMap.putString("hole", "1");
    dataMap.putString("front", "250");
    dataMap.putString("middle", "260");
    dataMap.putString("back", "270");

    return  dataMap;
}
```

}

**Mobile App manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ptrprograms.wearmessageapi" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

wearApp Code

```
public class WearMessageListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    Log.d("MessageAPI","onMessageReceived :: "+ messageEvent.getPath());
   /* if( messageEvent.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase( START_ACTIVITY ) ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        startActivity( intent );
    } else {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
    }*/

    showToast("onMessageReceived:: "+messageEvent.getPath());
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity( intent );

}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    super.onDataChanged(dataEventBuffer);
    Log.d("MessageAPI","onMessageReceived : onDataChanged: ");
}
```

}

wearApp manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <!-- <service android:name=".WearMessageListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>-->
    <service android:name=".WearMessageListenerService">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
        <!--<data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"
        android:path="/start_activity" />-->
        <!--<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />-->
       <!-- <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:path="/start_activity" />-->


    </service>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Problem is in `wearApp` in `WearMessageListenerService`. You don't call 

`super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);`

i.e you consume all messages. When you call super method you pass message to `Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(...`

2) I don't see in your wear app that you register MessageApi listener.

3) You mix MessageApi with Data Layer api.

4) In wear app in Main activity you need connect with google play services too. To register MessageApi listener in onConnected method.

5) Please check https://github.com/mariopce/android-wear-bilateral-communication. 
This is example of using MessageApi for 2-way communication (mobile-wear-mobile)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Github project is returning compilation error.             Error : android-wear-bilateral-communication-master\mobile\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(22) Error: The com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER action is deprecated. [WearableBindListener]
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />

Comment: Travis - it is a continuous integration tool like jenkins or teamcity - but for opensource project - say that all is fine.https://travis-ci.org/mariopce/android-wear-bilateral-communication
Maybe you have older version of playservice.

Comment: In gradle, i am using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0' version and Manifest <integer name="google_play_services_version">9452000</integer>. Let me know any changes in project settings.